# ¿Cómo mostrar que una posición esta incorrecta en un arreglo?

Tags: array, c, regex, dev-c++, char

Tengo un programa en lenguaje C que marca si el curp ingresado esta correcto o incorrecto, sin embargo necesito modificarlo para que la CURP que no es valida indique porque no es valida, en cada uno de sus posiciones
"Validación en cada posición"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<regex.h>

int my_match(char* pattern,char* buf){
int status,i;
int flag=REG_EXTENDED;
regmatch_t pmatch[1];
const size_t nmatch=1;
regex_t reg;
// compilando el modo regular
regcomp(&reg,pattern,flag);
// comparación de expresiones regulares y caché
status=regexec(&reg,buf,nmatch,pmatch,0);
// Imprima la cadena coincidente
for(i=pmatch[0].rm_so;i<pmatch[0].rm_eo;++i){
putchar(buf[i]);
}
printf("\n");
regfree(&reg);
return status;
}
int main(){
char pattern[1024]="^(([A-Z]{1}[AEIOUX]{1}[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])[HM]{1}(AS|BC|BS|CC|CS|CH|CL|CM|DF|DG|GT|GR|HG|JC|MC|MN|MS|NT|NL|OC|PL|QT|QR|SP|SL|SR|TC|TS|TL|VZ|YN|ZS|NE)[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{3}[0-9A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}))$";
char buf[1024]="OEVR670103HDFJLL08";
int status=my_match(pattern,buf);
if(status==REG_NOMATCH)
printf("No match!\n");
else if(0 == status){
printf("¡Partiendo el éxito! \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Normas generales para la construcción de la clave

Posición Posición 1-4 (La letra inicial y la primera vocal interna del primer apellido, la letra inicial del segundo apellido y la primera letra del nombre. En el caso de las mujeres casadas, se deberán usar los apellidos de soltera (alfabetica)).

Posición 5-10 (La fecha de nacimiento en el orden de año, mes y dia. Para el año se tomarán los dos últimos digitos, cuando el mes o el dia sea menor a diez, se antepondrà un cero.
1 de diciembre de 1995, Quedaria: 951201 (numèrica)).

Posición 11 (Sexo M para mujer y H para hombre (alfabetica).

Posición 12-13 (La letra inicial y última consonante, nacimiento conforme al Catálogo (SEGOB) de Entidades Federativas (alfabética) Ver el script)

Posición 14-16 (Integradas por las primeras consonantes internas del primer apellido, segundo apellido y nombre (alfabética).

Posición 17 (Diferenciador de homonimia y siglo, caracter progresivo asignado por la Secretaria de Gobernación que se emplea para diferenciar registros homónimos, 1-9 para fechas de nacimiento hasta el año 1999 y A-Z para fechas de nacimiento a partir de 2000 (alfanumérica).

Posición 18(Digito verificador, caracter asignado por la Secretaria de Gobernación a través de la aplicación de un algoritmo que permite calcular y verificar la correcta conformación y transcripción de la clave.

Comment: No entiendo el problema. C++ no es lo mismo que C. ¿Además, realmente necesitas usar regex? Quizá te sea más fácil resolverlo sin.

Comment: @Mateo El problema es en lenguaje C y como lo podría hacer sin regex?

Comment: Por ejemplo, si el carácter en la posición 11 tiene que ser M puedes usar `if (buf[10] == 'M') { ... }` y así.